# Maven - Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: windows, maven

I have recently installed Maven on my windows based laptop. But getting following error when running `mvn` just to test my installation:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Whoever when running `mvn -version` I am getting appropriate response:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:29:23+05:00)
Maven home: C:\apps\Maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Note that I am getting exactly same error when running `mvn install`, `mvn package`, `mvn clean` or any other Maven target in my maven project, while project doesn't have any dependency for `SLF4J`.

Comment: Can you confirm that `apache-maven-3.2.5/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar` exists, that you can open it and that it contains `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`?

Comment: @RobertScholte It does have that library but it doesn't have the class you have mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have `slf4j-simple` i actually have `slf4j-api`..

Comment: Very strange, because `slf4j-simple` is part of the distribution. How did you get this version?

Comment: From local mirror of apache-maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz

Comment: If I use your direct link, I can see slfj4-spimple-1.7.5.jar. Something must have gone wrong during unpacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually means that you have the `slf4j-api` library in your classpath without an `SLF4J binding` associated with it. Make sure to have exactly one of these binding jars in your classpath alongside the `slf4j-api` jar (also make sure the versions are compatible):

- slf4j-nop.jar,
- slf4j-simple.jar,
- slf4j-log4j12.jar,
- slf4j-jdk14.jar or
- logback-classic.jar

The `SLF4J` lists all such error codes on its FAQ page. You can find this issue and resolution documented [here](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

IIRC, this is merely a warning and won't affect your build process - or does it? If you didn't really mean to include the `SLF4J` libraries in your classpath, they would have been pulled in transitively. Use the `mvn dependency:tree` or the `m2eclipse`'s `Dependency Hierarchy` view to find the source of these the `SLF4J` related libraries and exclude them.