# maven: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: maven, tomcat7

I have maven project, here is a pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>tavridasite</groupId>
        <artifactId>tavridasite</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <build>
                <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.7</source>
                                        <target>1.7</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.4</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <url>http://localhost/manager/text</url>
                                        <server>TomcatServer</server>
                                        <path>/</path>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

I don't have here any dependencies.
When I do any mvn command as for example:

```
mvn tomcat7:undeploy
```

I have following error in console output:

```
  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
  SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I searched about this error, but all I get is relayed to  tag in pom.xml, however I don't have such tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Comment: but I run it outside of eclipse...

Comment: In that case it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138881/maven-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: Check your lib/ folder of the maven installation and make sure you have `slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar` and that the JAR is OK.

Comment: It don't helped... I added it to /usr/share/maven/lib

Comment: Why is Maven using `/usr/share/maven`? Did you install it using a package manager?